# Cannot delete old kernels

Tags: apt, kernel, delete

I ran the command:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image-
```

and got this list

```
rc linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic 3.13.0-51.84
rc linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic 3.13.0-52.86 rc linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic 3.13.0-53.89
rc linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic 3.13.0-54.91
rc linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic 3.13.0-55.94 rc linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic 3.13.0-57.95 rc linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic 3.13.0-58.97
rc linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic 3.13.0-59.98
rc linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic 3.13.0-61.100
ii linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic 3.13.0-62.102
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic 3.13.0-30.55 rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic 3.13.0-46.79
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic 3.13.0-49.83
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic 3.13.0-51.84
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic 3.13.0-52.86 rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic 3.13.0-53.89
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic 3.13.0-54.91
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic 3.13.0-55.94
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic 3.13.0-57.95
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic 3.13.0-58.97
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic 3.13.0-59.98
rc linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic 3.13.0-61.100
ii linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic 3.13.0-62.102
ii linux-image-generic 3.13.0.62.69
```

So I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic
```

and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Package 'linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic' is not installed, so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So do I or do I not have unused old kernels on my system and how should I remove them??

Comment: what is output of  `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

Answer (score 4):

In the first two columns of your `dpkg -l` generated list of kernels  you will find information on the package as follows:

1. Column (desired action):

   ```
   u = Unknown
   i = Install
   h = Hold
   r = Remove
   p = Purge
   ```
2. Column (package status):

   ```
   n = Not-installed
   c = Config-files
   H = Half-installed
   U = Unpacked
   F = Half-configured
   W = Triggers-awaiting
   t = Triggers-pending
   i = Installed
   ```

For your first example

```
rc linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic 3.13.0-51.84
```

it will hence tell us that the packages was removed (`r`) but the configuration files are still there (`c`). Only those kernels marked `ii` are actually installed on your system. Autoremove will only remove obsolete kernels but will leave the configuration files.

To also remove these we'd have to purge an installed package (`sudo apt-get purge <package>`) but leaving them does no harm and they do not need much hard drive space.

Answer (score 0):

According to your output all old kernels have been removed already.

You have only kernel  3.13.0-62 installed.

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic

In the past I have had success with:

## sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic

If that doesn't work try reading this great article:

http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/

Answer (score -1):

First remove the headers. Give `ls /usr/src | grep linux-headers` to see your headers, and then use purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-xxx
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-xxx
```